# Unable to access dockerized Neo4j webinterface through dockerized Traefik

Tags: docker, neo4j, reverse-proxy, traefik

I'm trying to access the webinterface of a dockerized *neo4j*-instance with the help of *traefik* as a reverse-proxy.

I can reach the neo4j-instance's webinterface by navigating to `myDomain.demo:7479/browser`. However I want to be able to reach it by simply navigating to `myDomain.demo/neo4j/myNeo`, so I don't have to remember the port numbers when using multiple neo4j-instances on the same machine. 
Sadly I'm not able to reach the webinterface this way, instead I'm shown a **blank page** which asks me for credentials. I guess this is atleast a good sign, since normally when accessing the webinterface I have to enter my db-credentials into a GUI-mask to connect to my neo4j-db. However this should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgW6J.png) instead of the simple browser-popup I'm seeing.

Cleary I can't be the first one who tries to access multiple neo4j-instances and their corresponding webinterface behind a reverse-proxy, but I can't wrap my head around how to do it. Here are my setup-commands:

**Dockerized Traefik-Proxy**

```
docker run --name proxy -p 80:80 -p 8080:8080 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
traefik \
--api --loglevel=debug --entryPoints="Name:http  Address::80" \
--docker --docker.endpoint="unix://var/run/docker.sock"
```

**Dockerized Neo4j-Instance** (which is working fine without proxy)

```
docker run --name myNeo -d --publish=7479:7474 --publish=7701:7687 \
--label traefik.frontend.rule="Host:myDomain.demo;Path:/neo4j/myNeo" \
--label traefik.backend=myNeo \
--label traefik.port=7474 \
neo4j:latest
```

(for the sake of simplicity I've dropped multiple volume allocations in the neo4j-docker command.)

I noticed that when manually navigating to `myDomain.demo:7479`, I get redirected to `myDomain.demo:7479/browser`. Maybe Traefic can't handle that redirect and this is why I'm served a blank page without errors?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Three things:

1. The `Path` rule is an exact match only. `Path:/example` will match `/example`, but not `/example/bacon`. You probably want to use `PathPrefix` instead.
2. If you can't run `myDomain.demo:7479/neo4j/myNeo/browser`, then you will not be able to use subdirectories for routing. You need to configure your application to listen on a subpath. Neo4j needs to know its path so it can generate links etc.
3. Once you can get neo4j working on a subpath, then you can use traefik to route to the custom domain/port.

Comment: Thank you for your help. However I couldn't find out how to modify neo4j to listen on subpaths, so I deceided to abandon Traefik and use nginx instead.